# resizing a figure messes up the whole document

Tags: graphics

My problem is simple: I have one figure that is too large. I resize it to half in an attempt to make it smaller, but doing so changes the other figures' position.

Here's what I mean:

This is the original code:

```
\documentclass [10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/franc/OneDrive/Documentos/desISTo/e1}}


\hyphenation{mate-mática recu-perar}

\begin{document}
\section* {Simulação no LTSpice}
\subsection* {4.1 - Ponto de Funcionamento em Repouso}
Fazendo a análise do circuito com uma tensão Vs constante, os andares de amplificação são "isolados" do resto do circuito devido aos condensadores C1 e C2, fazendo com que a única fonte de tensão a alimentar o circuito seja Vcc. Fazendo a simulação do circuito no regime Dc op point no LTSpice, obteve-se os seguintes resultados:
\begin {figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{Screenshot (277).png}
    \caption{Valores das tensões e correntes nos pontos pedidos.}
\end {figure}

\subsection* {4.2 - Análise AC e determinação das impedâcias Ri1 e Ri2}
Para calcular as impedâncias de entrada de cada um dos transístores, primeiro determinou-se qual a frequência a qual correspondia à voltagem $v_{o1}$ mais alto. Através do cursores observou-se que esta frequência é de aproximadamente 16.8 KHz, a qual originava uma tensão $\approx$ 3.81 V. Todos os cálculos seguintes são realisados nesta frequência.
\[
    R_{i1} = \frac{v_{in}}{i_{in}}  \approx \text{19.84 K}\Omega
    \qquad
    R_{i2} = \frac{v_{O1}}{i_{B2}}  \approx \text{208.3 K}\Omega
\]
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{impedância Ri1.png} % first figure itself
        \caption{Determinação da impedância de entrada de Q1}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{impedância ri2.png} % second figure itself
        \caption{Determinação da impedância de entrada de Q2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\subsection*{4.3 - Análise AC e determinação dos ganhos $A_{1L}$, $A_{2L}$, $A_{v}^{'}$, $A_{v}$ } 
Ao dividir as tensões de saída de cada transístor pela sua respetiva tensão de entrada, pode-se calcular o ganho de cada um. Uma maneira de fazer tal tarefa é implementar o gráfico do quociente entre essas duas grandezas a partir do gráfico de cada uma. Assim, obteve-se os seguintes valores (lineares):
\[
    A_{1L} = \frac{v_{O1}}{v_{in}}  \approx \text{6}
    \qquad
    A_{2L} = \frac{v_{out}}{v_{O1}}  \approx \text{0.96297}
\]
\[
    A_{v}^{'} = \frac{v_{out}}{v_{in}}  \approx \text{5.79}
    \qquad
    A_{v} = \frac{v_{out}}{v_{S}}  \approx \text{3.609}
\]
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{ganho a1L.png} % first figure itself
        \caption{Determinação do ganho de Q1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{ganho a2L.png} % second figure itself
        \caption{Determinação do ganho de Q2}
    \end{subfigure}
        \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{ganho av'.png} % first figure itself
        \caption{Determinação do ganho $A_{v}^{'}$}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{ganho av.png} % second figure itself
        \caption{Determinação do ganho $A_{v}$}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\subsection* {4.4 - Análise no domínio do tempo para $v_{S}$ sinuisodal de amplitude 100 mV e frequência 2000 Hz}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{4.4.png}
\caption{Visualização de $v_{S}(t)$, $v_{in}(t)$, $v_{o1}(t)$, $v_{out}(t)$}
\end{figure}
\subsection*{4.5 - Distorção de $v_{o1}$}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{4.5.png}
\caption{Visualização de $v_{S}(t)$, $v_{o1}(t)$, $v_{ce1}(t)$ com amplitude do sinal de entrada 1 V}
\end{figure}
\subsection*{4.6 - Cálculo da largura de banda}
Para calcuar a largura de banda, determinou-se a frequência correspodente ao primeiro valor de 7 dB (10 dB - 3 dB) a ser alcançado ($f_{L}$ = 404.787 Hz) e a frequência para os segundos 7 dB ($f_{H}$ = 647.62 KHz). Substituindo $f_{H}$ por $f_{L}$ obtêm-se $\Delta f$ = 646.61744 KHz.
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{4.6.png}
\caption{Visualização de $|v_{out}(\omega)/v_{S}(\omega)|$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This gives the following output:

[image]
[image]
[image]

But when I change
`\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{Screenshot (277).png}`
to
`\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Screenshot (277).png}`
this happens:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm completely lost. Any help?

Comment: _but doing so changes the other figures' position._ I typically use `[H]` and not `[h]` to fix the figure position where it is.  Try to see if this helps.  Need `\usepackage{float}` for `H`

Comment: @Nasser thanks, it worked!

Comment: Don't use just `[h]` if the figure is large it gets moved really far away. Learn to use the proper `[htp]` or `[htbp]` this places the figure as close as possible which is what you want. Additionally, no `[H]` is not a good solution. Thirdly, always refer to your figures by number (via label and ref), never on the figure below we see... Then you don't have to rely on the exact placement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a small tip on this site: avoid showing code that can't be compiled directly, for example because it calls image files that we can't have. Use the `test-image-a`, `test-image-b`, etc, provided by `graphicx`.

Back to your question, there are three tricks that I sometimes use in this situation:

- Use more placement instructions: `[!htb]` instead of `[h]`. `!` forces LaTeX to accept using more space for figures in a page, and `htb` gives more placement options.
- Use the `H` placement option provided by the package `float`. Not something that you want to do by default, but sometimes it's still useful, especially to avoid (for example) that an image inside a section is thrown *before* that section if it's near the top of a page.
- Don't make the figure a float: you can use `\includgraphics` with no `figure` environment.

I don't like the third possibility because you lose all the automatic goodness provided by the `figure` environment, but with the other two I almost never run into problems like the one you describe.

Edit: modified the first "trick" following daleif's comment.

Comment: You're forgetting the placeins package. IMO H should be kept for only very special documents.

Comment: To be honest, in almost every case, just using `!` is enough, so I haven't looked for alternative solutions seriously for a while. Nevertheless, I'll have a look at `placeins`, thanks.

Comment: As I write in my comment to the op, just using `[h]` is wrong and leads to many problems. One might _reduce_ to it in certain situations, but it should not be the goto value.

Comment: Personally I always use `[!htb]` and I should have mentioned it, you're right. I'll edit my answer.